# Loop threw Thread Group with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I got a thread group of 10 users. I want to to connect these 10 users to an URL path `mysite.com/1`.

Then I want to loop a second time on these thread group and connect them to `mysite.com/2`.

And I need to repeat this process 10 times (i.e until mysite.com/10)...

I there a simple way of achieving that? I've already tried to use counter but what it does is connecting user1 to `/1`, user2 to `/2` and so on...

Answer (score -1):

1. Add [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to your Thread Group and put the following expression to the "Condition" area:

   ```
   ${__javaScript(${counter} < 11,)}
   ```
2. Add [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element as a child of the While Controller and configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter Counter configuration]
3. In your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler refer the incrementing value as `${counter}` where required.

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) to learn how to properly generate incrementing values in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't see the usefulness of the "while controller" here, doesn't the counter stops by itselfs when it reaches and restarts from 1? I tried your solution but it give me the same result as with the simple counter : user1 is connecting to /1, user2 to /2 ... user10 to /10 then it stops.

Comment: While Controller is for looping child(ren) request(s) for 10 times

Comment: Ok, another implementation: configure 10 loops on Thread Group level and use URL like `mysite.com/${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)}`

Comment: I tried it with the ${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)} method but it starts by connecting all the users to /1 but then stops. I used a "loop controller" but it doesn't seems to work neither on the recording controller nor on the thread group (I tried both) : [image](http://imgur.com/ktYW1wV). Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You need to define loops under **THREAD GROUP**

Comment: I tried both, but even under the [thread group](http://imgur.com/d8SRak7) it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145431/discussion-between-mit-and-dmitri-t).

Comment: I fail to see what else I can add, see [this evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89pqw.png) demonstrating that the approach works. Just in case check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to familiarize yourself with [JMeter Functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) concept.

Comment: Where is your loop controller on your screen? Or could you upload the jmx file please?

Comment: There is no loop controller, I repeat 3rd time, loops needs to be defined on Thread Group level

Comment: Could you please come for two minutes on the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145431/discussion-between-mit-and-dmitri-t)?

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but it isn't doing what I want, I found this note about it on another thread: "It doesn't actually loop in any sort of chronological sense, even if your Test Plan has Run Thread Groups consecutively checked. What it does do is multiply your thread group and run all multiples concurrently."

Comment: That's why I played this trick with [Test Action sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) and [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) (just for demo purposes), not sure if this is required for your scenario.

Comment: That isn't like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut?